# Do I need to use core data with web server Database?

Tags: mysql, ipad, core-data

I am developing a game (ipad), the game will need an online database for storage, becuz it will need others players data to play multi-player stuffs.

I have been reading core data tutorials, but so far, what I read are all for internal iphone storage (using internal sqlite3 etc).

My question is that:

1. If I were using online webserver database (connecting/read/write/update by using php), do I need to use the internal core data?

More details for question 1: For example, I fetch a player's data like username, level, gold, hp, exp etc, do I need to wrap to core data, or I just simply create an NSObject for storing the player information, and using share manager to share with others classes that need it?

1. What are the tips and technique for developing iPad games with web-services(mysql via php HTTP POST). (FYI, I found this ASIHTTPRequest library, and I find it quite useful, and I am using it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data isn't primarily for storage. Instead it is a means of creating the model layer of an Model-View-Controller design app (which the Apple API uses.) Persisting the model to disk is really just an option.

Core Data handles both size and complexity in models. If your app just fetches dumb data from the web server e.g. a list of static values, then you probably don't need Core Data. However, if your app fetches data from the web server and then manipulates it in a complex manner, then Core Data will provide you many benefits.

A lot times, if you don't use Core Data, you can end up essentially rewriting Core Data just to manage all the relationships between your data objects and the rest of the API.

If you plan on working a lot with the Apple API, you should learn Core Data regardless of the source or destination of your data. It will save you a lot of time in the long run. The important thing to remember is that its not a database wrapper.